# GDB disassembly, what is the -0xc(%rbp) position?

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

I am in school and doing an assignment where I disassembly binary files and then interpret them and build a c++ program from them (reverse engineering).  My main question is what does the "c" position represent when referring to the rbp.  Normally there is a number in its location that tells me how many bytes past the rbp a variable is stored, but I am a little confused by the "c" in this case.  I have been searching high and low to see I this just means 0 bytes past the rbp or not, but searching forums for this hasn't turned up any results and it is hard to phrase a search for the "c" position in a way that doesn't just give me a ton of random posts that are just "c" language related".  Thanks so much for you help everyone!

The original instruction:

mov    %eax,-0xc(%rbp)

Comment: `0xc` is a hexadecimal number. `c` is 12.

Comment: And `-0xc` is `-12`

Comment: in this case it uses the C/C++ syntax for a hex number.  0xC means 1100 binary and 12 decimal, etc (just like C++).  in this case it means take the value in rbp, subtract 12 and use that result as an address.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone.